# Get access to LLVM IR of C library function call

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I have a C code(called a.c for example) that calls function such us `printf`, `textcolor` and `gotoxy` from stdio.h/curses.h. LLVM-IR for a.c will only declare these functions and show these functions have been called meaning it wont have detailed IR for implementing these functions in a.ll. Is there any way I can get access to those IR or put all the implementations(IR of a.c+ IR of those function calls) together into one .ll file? I'm not knowing LLVM very well, so please let me know if I've made some conceptual mistakes.

Comment: Err... Your C library is _already compiled and assembled_; To obtain the LLVM IR for it would require finding the C library and doing some serious disassembly-to-IR work. This is hard to impossible to achieve in the general case and if the library is obfuscated in any way it may prove unfeasible. You also probably don't need the IR representation of the C library at all. If you really want this IR you'd have to build by hand your C library with Clang and make it spit out LLVM IR instead of binary executables. And that of course assumes you have the source code for your C library.

Comment: As Eli said, you have to compile all your libraries (including libc) statically with Clang with -flto, and then dump your combined module by passing --also-emit-llvm option to the Gold plugin (assuming you're using gold, of course).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not get this from *your* program, because it doesn't contain those functions. Even if statically linked, the executable most likely will not, because libc (where `printf` and other C library functions come from) exists on your machine as an object file, not LLVM IR.

What you *can* do is compile one of the C libraries (try something small and simple like `ulibc` or `newlib`) with LLVM. Then you can emit LLVM IR from that. FWIW, the Chrome Portable Native Client project does this (with `newlib`) - you can use the [directions on this page](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/developing-pnacl) to build it and replicate the steps yourself.